# get Highest value for each year python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I'm having an issue with getting the highest value for each year from a large data set using python.

```
with open('GlobalLandTemperaturesByCity.csv') as csvfile:
data = pd.read_csv(csvfile)

changedata = data[data['City'].str.match('Pokhara') & data['Country'].str.match('Nepal')]
changedata = changedata.set_index(changedata['dt'])
#changedata = changedata['dt'].to_datetime()
usedata = changedata[changedata['dt']> '1970-1-1 01:00:00']
print(usedata)
```

This yields

```
                    dt  AverageTemperature  AverageTemperatureUncertainty  \
dt                                                                          
1970-10-01  1970-10-01              16.388                          0.395   
1970-11-01  1970-11-01              10.569                          1.017   
1970-12-01  1970-12-01               7.455                          0.194   
1971-01-01  1971-01-01               5.508                          0.435   
1971-02-01  1971-02-01               7.458                          0.413   
...                ...                 ...                            ...   
2013-05-01  2013-05-01              20.069                          0.719   
2013-06-01  2013-06-01              21.168                          0.407   
2013-07-01  2013-07-01              21.503                          0.316   
2013-08-01  2013-08-01              21.541                          0.478   
2013-09-01  2013-09-01                 NaN                            NaN   

           City Country Latitude Longitude  
dt                                              
1970-10-01  Pokhara   Nepal   28.13N    84.55E  
1970-11-01  Pokhara   Nepal   28.13N    84.55E  
1970-12-01  Pokhara   Nepal   28.13N    84.55E  
1971-01-01  Pokhara   Nepal   28.13N    84.55E  
1971-02-01  Pokhara   Nepal   28.13N    84.55E  
...             ...     ...      ...       ...  
2013-05-01  Pokhara   Nepal   28.13N    84.55E  
2013-06-01  Pokhara   Nepal   28.13N    84.55E  
2013-07-01  Pokhara   Nepal   28.13N    84.55E  
2013-08-01  Pokhara   Nepal   28.13N    84.55E  
2013-09-01  Pokhara   Nepal   28.13N    84.55E
```

I need a way to not get every month of data but just the highest or lowest for each year?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any issue here. You print all data after 1970. Now you calculate the yearly averages and that's your result.

Comment: What did you try? Maybe something using `group_by()`, `min()`, and `max()` can help.

Answer (score 3):

if your index is a true datetime index:

```
# Optional fix for datetime-like str index:
# df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df \
    .resample('1y') \
    .AverageTemperature \
    .agg([min, max])
```

**Example**

```
dr = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2020-01-01')
df = pd.DataFrame(range(len(dr)), index=dr, columns=['AverageTemperature'])

df.resample('1y').AverageTemperature.agg([min, max])
```

**Result**

```
             min   max
2010-12-31     0   364
2011-12-31   365   729
2012-12-31   730  1095
2013-12-31  1096  1460
2014-12-31  1461  1825
2015-12-31  1826  2190
2016-12-31  2191  2556
2017-12-31  2557  2921
2018-12-31  2922  3286
2019-12-31  3287  3651
2020-12-31  3652  3652
```

**Plotting**

To plot this you can simply call

```
df \
    .resample('1y') \
    .AverageTemperature \
    .agg([min, max]) \
    .plot()
```

Comment: Might be a bit more illustrative if the example did 1 year resampling, but it’s got my vote nonetheless

Comment: the data I get back is the date and an index, as follows 
2000-01-01     0
2000-01-02     1
2000-01-03     2
2000-01-04     3
2000-01-05     4

I need to return the temperature and date so I can plot them.. what would i need to change?

Comment: see updated answer for plotting and column selection, which i forgot to add :)